# Spring Redis pubsub: onMessage callback data manipulation not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, publish-subscribe, spring-data-redis

I have implemented MessageListener and override onMessage(..) method like this:

```
 @Override
public void onMessage(Message message, byte[] pattern) {

    log.info("callback--- onMessage:{}", message.toString());

   // String msg=message.toString();
  //  if(Util.isProperJson(message.toString()))
    {
        String msg=new String(message.toString()); //new String(message.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        JSONObject eventInfoJson= new JSONObject(msg);
       EmailInfo eventInfo=Util.getDeserializedObj(eventInfoJson, EmailInfo.class);


        googleCalendarService.createGoogleCalendarEvent(eventInfo);
    }
```

when I print the message.toString or convert byteArray of message.getBody() to string, I get the proper jsonString. But when I try to convert it to jsonObject to deserialize into a object, I get error-saying that it is not valid json string, though it is valid as I copied the string to another place and converted to JSONObject without any issue.  I am using org.json to convert into JSONObject. My console string data:

```
"{\"cc\":[\"email1\",\"emai2\"],\"meetingName\":\"string\",\"meetingPlace\":\"string\",\"subject\":\"string\",\"recipient\":[\"string\"],\"description\":\"string\",\"startTime\":{\"dayOfWeek\":\"THURSDAY\",\"month\":\"FEBRUARY\",\"hour\":12,\"dayOfYear\":35,\"year\":2021,\"dayOfMonth\":4,\"monthValue\":2,\"nano\":102000000,\"chronology\":{\"calendarType\":\"iso8601\",\"id\":\"ISO\"},\"minute\":0,\"second\":20},\"endTime\":{\"dayOfWeek\":\"THURSDAY\",\"month\":\"FEBRUARY\",\"hour\":12,\"dayOfYear\":35,\"year\":2021,\"dayOfMonth\":4,\"monthValue\":2,\"nano\":102000000,\"chronology\":{\"calendarType\":\"iso8601\",\"id\":\"ISO\"},\"minute\":30,\"second\":20},\"body\":\"string\",\"projectName\":\"string\"}";
```

Error Log:

> 2021-02-03 16:15:54.855 ERROR o.s.d.r.l.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter - Listener execution failed
> org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
> at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:507)
> at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:222)
> at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:406)
> at com.tigerit.soa.redis.RedisMessageSubscriber.onMessage(RedisMessageSubscriber.java:41)
> at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:297)
> at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:250)
> at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.processMessage(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:240)
> at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.lambda$dispatchMessage$0(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:986)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What am I missing here :(  ?

Comment: is the first " included in your String ?

Comment: @CyrilG. in console print, I got that whole

Comment: then your JSON is invalid as it should start with { you need to remove the enclosing quotes

Comment: after seeing your comment, I tried removing those " from first and last, no luck :(  !